# Problem running the WAM wave model

Tags: ocean, models, waves, numerical-modelling, software

In the WAM Cycle 4 wave model, why doesn't the model work for the year 1999?

When I tried to run for the year 1999 the model does not produce any results.

Comment: Hi Pubali, I don't know whether we have any experts on that particular model here, but if we do, you are going to need to provide a *lot* more information for them to be able to help. Does it work for other years? What have you tried? What exactly happens when you try for 1999?

Comment: Have you tried contacting people that can help you with WAM directly, like the people at KNMI that originally developed it (http://www.knmi.nl, Gerrit.Burgers@knmi.nl) or at USACE (Robert.E.Jensen@usace.army.mil)?

Comment: I am voting to close this question because relevant information is missing (input data; for which years DOES it work; ...) and it was made no attempt to improve the question.